# XOR failing to decrypt certain files

Tags: file, encryption, c++17

The following code manages to encrypt any file I try, but it only manages to decrypt .txt files. When I try decrypting .mp3, .png, .mp4 files which I have encrypted, it fails to do so.

So I am wondering why this is the case? If it successfully manages to decrypt .txt files, why does it fail to do so with the other file formats I've tried (mentioned before)? Because if I understand XOR encryption correct it returns the original string running it a second time, thus I should be able to reopen the file and it should work normally since the data should be decrypted, r-right?

Feel free to bash me if I am being stupid here.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>


int main() {
const std::filesystem::path& path = "folder\\";

FILE* pFile, *pFile1;

char key = '¤';

//get files in dir
for (const std::filesystem::directory_entry &p : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path)) {
    std::filesystem::path filename = p.path().filename();
    std::string tmp = path.string() + filename.string();

    fopen_s(&pFile, tmp.c_str(), "rb");

    if (pFile) {
        //for size purposes
        char* buffer = 0;
        long size;
        fseek(pFile, 0L, SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(pFile);
        fseek(pFile, 0L, SEEK_SET);
        //rewind(pFile);

        buffer = new char[size+1];

        //set to zero to remove random chars
        memset(buffer, 0, size+1);

        //get filecontent
        fgets(buffer, size+1, pFile);

        fclose(pFile);

        //XOR-crypt text/data
        for (int i = 0; i < size+1; i++) {
            buffer[i] ^= key;
        }

        //open for writing
        fopen_s(&pFile1, tmp.c_str(), "wb");

        //write back to file
        fputs(buffer, pFile);

        fclose(pFile1);
        delete[] buffer;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can't read binary data with fgets.

Comment: And the reason why you can't read binary data with `fgets` is, it does not report number of characters read. You have to search for 0 byte indicating end of string, *which is put in the buffer by `fgets`*. But if you are reading binary data, the data itself may also contain 0 bytes, and you have no way of knowing if a 0 means end of string read, or if it was just a byte in the data.

Comment: I suppose you're reffering to rhe "rb" and "wb"? Well I tried only using "r" and "w", but still to no avail. :(

Comment: Uhm.  Why are you using XOR to encrypt?

Comment: No, they're not referring to "rb" and "wb".  Those are correct.  ("r" and "w" are incorrect.)  They're telling you that you must not use `fgets` to collect data from the input file.  Instead of `fgets`, use `fread`.  Also, you must not use `fputs` to send data into the output file.  Instead of `fputs`, use `fwrite`.

Comment: Hey @ottomeister thanks for clearing it up for me, I got it working now.